Should one say "on their lap" or "on their laps"?
I need to describe a group of pupils. Should I say:
"Some pupils are sitting with their bags on their laps" or
"some pupils are sitting with their bags on their lap." or
"Some pupils are sitting with their bag on their lap."?
Which one is relevant here: the distributive plural or the distributive singular?

How many laps are there?

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70186/phone-or-phones https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/303139/does-it-make-a-difference-whether-you-singular-or-plural-version-here https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/110914/they-write-in-their-school-diary-or-diaries etc

Compare singular Some boys fear their father and plural Some boys fear their fathers. They're both fine, and it's not really worth trying to identify some nuance of semantic difference. It's just a stylistic choice.

Your question has 4 cases.

are sitting with their bag on their lap

are sitting with their bag on their laps

are sitting with their bags on their lap

are sitting with their bags on their laps


Technically speaking, if there are more than one bag/lap, you should use plural forms. Still, 'their' already implies there are most likely more than one bag/lap. So the distributive singular can be applied.
For example, in "We have a nose.", 'a nose' is a distributive singualr. 'We' already implies 'plural concept'.
All your examples are at least grammatically correct.

I mean on their lap or laps...

'lap' is composed of two legs and we use this word like 'in my lap', 'on her lap', 'on their laps', etc. Technically, 'on their laps' are correct. Still, 'their' already expresses the plural concept. So the aforementioned distributive singular can be applied: on their laps (o), on their lap (o)

A person's 'lap' is the flat area above their knees when they are sitting down. It's normally referred to in the singular, even though it involves both legs.

I already said: 'lap' is composed of two legs and is used like 'on my lap', 'on her lap'. The OP's question is their lap or their laps. And I said 'their laps' are also correct. 'their laps' mean: Tom's lap, Jane's lap, Alex's lap, ,,, . 'their laps' doesn't mean a lap consisting of both legs.

I suppose you could leverage "singular they" to defend #3 above, but I don't buy it. And #2 isn't remotely credible. The choice is between #1 and #4.

@FumbleFingers - I can't imagine saying 'the schoolboys wore a cap on their head'.

@MichaelHarvey: That's #1 above. The schoolboys wore a cap on their heads is #2, which doesn't really work, and certainly not as They wore their cap on their heads

Let's be loyal to op's examples.(lap and bag)
